# Displaying Complex API in flutter ListView

Tags: android, json, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a complex API which has a json array.  i want to display the details in the JSON in a flutter listView.
The following is my json

```
{
    "hours": [
        {
            "time": "2021-03-23T00:00:00+00:00",
            "waveHeight": {
                "icon": 1.35,
                "meteo": 1.25,
                "noaa": 1.28,
                "sg": 1.25
            }
        },
{
            "time": "2021-03-23T00:00:00+00:00",
            "waveHeight": {
                "icon": 1.35,
                "meteo": 1.25,
                "noaa": 1.28,
                "sg": 1.25
            }
        },
    ],
}
```

This is the fetch data function

```
void getJsonData() async {
    String url2 =
        'https://api.stormglass.io/v2/weather/point?lat=5.9774&lng=80.4288&params=waveHeight&start=2021-03-23&end2021-03-24';
    
    String apiKey =
        'sxascdsvfdyhujn5787654gb-7a54-11eb-8302-0242ac130002';
    print('0');

    try {
      Response response = await get(Uri.parse(url2),
          headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: apiKey});

      var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List data = jsonData["hours"];

      data.forEach((element) {
        Map obj = element;
        Map wave = obj['waveHeight'];
        String time = obj['time'];

        print(time);
        double icon = wave['icon'];

        print(icon);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

All the JSON data are successfully fetched and displayed in the console. But I want to display the data in a flutter ListView. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

firstly define a new class

```
class Wave {
  final DateTime time;
  final double icon;
  final double meteo;
  final double noaa;
  final double sg;

  Wave ({
    this.time,
    this.icon,
    this.meteo,
    this.noaa,
    this.sg,
  });
}
```

create an empty list

```
List<Wave> _data = [];
```

Edit your code with the below code

```
      final _extractedData = json.decode(result.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

      List<Wave> _fetchedData = [];

      _extractedData['hours'].forEach((value) {
        _fetchedData.add(Wave(
          time: value['time'],
          icon: value['icon'],
          meteo: value['meteo'],
          noaa: value['noaa'],
          sg: value['sg'],
        ));
      });
      _data = _fetchedData;
```

`_data` has the new list of data received from json.

Comment: @Learnado if this code has helped you, then please give it a tick.

Comment: It is working but when I print the _data it shows as Instance of 'Wave'

Comment: obviously it will show that as it is Instance of Wave. _data is a list of type Wave. to use it, try `_data[index].time`. If you are not familiar with coding, please try using help of some course. Flutter is an easy language to learn. But if you don't have a coding background or you are new in it, it will get very difficult.